# How get DefaultMutableTreeNode using node text or node value in jsf

Tags: jsf-2, icefaces

I am having problem with my icefaces tree, I am not getting the current node value in backing bean. So, I decided to get the value using nodevalue (text). Can anyone tell me, how can I get the DefaultMutableTreeNode using nodevalue (string) so I can set it as currentnode.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually guessing on your question.  I'm not exactly sure what you mean but I'm going to take a shot.  It may help you.

This is from an old project of mine.  I would also suggest using Primefaces now.  Much easier to work with, easier to theme, faster(from my experience), and more components.

```
 <ice:tree id="tree"
                          value="#{TreeController.model}"
                          var="node"
                          hideRootNode="false"
                          hideNavigation="false"
                          imageDir="./xmlhttp/css/rime/css-images/">
                    <ice:treeNode>
                        <f:facet name="icon">
                            <ice:panelGroup style="display: inline">
                                <h:graphicImage value="#{node.userObject.icon}"/>
                            </ice:panelGroup>
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="content">
                            <ice:panelGroup  style="display: inline">
                                <ice:commandLink disabled="#{!PkgLineTableController.tableRendered}"
                                                 actionListener="#{TreeController.locationNodeSelected}">
                                    <f:param name="treeId"
                                             value="#{node.userObject.tree.treeId}"/>
                                    <f:param name="name" value="#{node.userObject.text}"/>
                                    <ice:outputText  id="TreeNode"
                                                     value="#{node.userObject.text}"/>
                                </ice:commandLink>
                            </ice:panelGroup>
                        </f:facet>
                    </ice:treeNode>
                </ice:tree>
```

Backing bean:

```
 private DefaultMutableTreeNode findTreeNode(String nodeId) {

        DefaultMutableTreeNode rootNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) getModel().getRoot();
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node;
        TreeObject tmp;
        Enumeration nodes = rootNode.depthFirstEnumeration();
        while (nodes.hasMoreElements()) {
            node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) nodes.nextElement();
            tmp = (TreeObject) node.getUserObject();
            if (nodeId.equals(String.valueOf(tmp.getTree().getTreeId()))) {
                return node;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     *  Method fired when a node is selected on the tree.  This calls a few methods from the packageLineBean to build the
     *  package line list.
     */
    public void locationNodeSelected(ActionEvent event) {

        PkgLineTableController pkgLineTableController = PkgLineTableController.getCurrentInstance();

        String tree_id = FacesUtils.getRequestParameter("treeId");
        selectedTreeNodeName = FacesUtils.getRequestParameter("name");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = findTreeNode(tree_id);
        selectedTreeObject = ((TreeObject) node.getUserObject());

        pkgLineTableController.getPkgLineTreeList().clear();
        pkgLineTableController.digPackageLines(Integer.parseInt(tree_id));
        pkgLineTableController.setEffect(new Appear());

        WrapSpecTableController.getCurrentInstance().getWrapSpecList().clear();
    }
```